# regex pattern in c# doesn't return result

Tags: .net, regex

I have a pattern `(?<=.*?\*)([\-\+])(.\d{0,2})(?=(d))`
which will return -45 in a string *-45d using http://regexstorm.net/tester when I use this pattern in my c# code it doesn't return anything.

```
string text= "*-4d";
string pattern = @"(<?<=.*?\*)([\-\+])(.\d{0,2})(?=(d))";
var result= Regex.Match(text, pattern);
```

any ideas why this is?

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTtWXn)

Comment: Shouldn't `@"(<?<...` be `@"(?<...`?

Comment: Your pattern in C# code different for the first line one. First is correct.

Comment: may be you have already tried this, but are you looking for something like this: [-+]\d{0,2}d? -> returns (+/- with two digits and an optional 'd') your pattern doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks Yorye your suggestion worked in the .NET code.  Grant, I tried my pattern in regexstorm.net/tester and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you *thought* the regex was supposed to match but most likely the problem is here:

```
 (<?<=.*?\*)
```

That will match something like this: `<?<=some_arbitary_text_followed_by_a_*`

If you want to do a negative look-behind, the syntax should be `?<=` but there is also the problem of the `.*?` which is incompatible with a look-behind. Something like this should work though:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\*)([\-\+])(.\d{0,2})(?=(d))";
```